# is it possible to read or fetch checkbox data from firebase to android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to access values or data from a checkbox in which the user selected courses. I am trying to access this data from firebase to Android Studio and it is posing a challenge. I can access the student Id from the database, but not the selected courses of the user under the user information.

Here is a description of my Firebase real-time database.

```
├── userId1
│   ├── studentId: "someStudentId1"
│   ├── email: "user1@example.com"
│   ├── role: "student"
│   └── selectedCourses
│       ├── MTH1010: true
│       ├── ENG1020: true
│       └── ...
├── userId2
│   ├── studentId: "someStudentId2"
│   ├── email: "user2@example.com"
│   ├── role: "student"
│   └── selectedCourses
│       ├── MTH1010: true
│       ├── ENG1020: true
│       └── ...
└── ...

And here is my code to access the selectedCourses 

 private void populateSpinner2(String userId) {
        Log.d("Firebase", "Fetching selected courses for user: " + userId);
        DatabaseReference userSelectedCoursesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("users").child(userId)
                .child("selectedCourses");

        userSelectedCoursesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<String> selectedCourses = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataSnapshot courseSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // Use boolean value directly instead of getValue(Boolean.class)
                    boolean isSelected = courseSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);

                    // Check if the course is selected (true)
                    if (isSelected) {
                        // Add the course ID to the list
                        selectedCourses.add(courseSnapshot.getKey());
                    }
                }

                // populate spinner2 with these course IDs
                populateSpinner2WithCourses(selectedCourses);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(GRADE.this, "Failed to fetch selected courses: " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateSpinner2WithCourses(List<String> selectedCourses) {
        // Use the course IDs from selectedCourses to populate spinner2
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(GRADE.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, selectedCourses);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I am expecting to access the users selected courses and display them in a dropdown menu.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: What you're after is pretty clear but we need to see the code you attempted. Additionally, be sure to tag the question with the Firebase product you're using as there are many. You are likely using Firestore or the Realtime Database, so add the tag (and perhaps your coding platform as well).

Comment: I've made the necessary changes and updated the question with a sample of the code that I was using kindly assist. @AlexMamo

Comment: Is your `onDataChange` even triggered?